# need working example of how to share "session" data between two .net 2.0 web applications running on the same domain

Tags: .net, session, asp.net-2.0, session-state

i would like a working example, that uses a asp.net session state server, to share a session variable between two .net 2.0 web applications both running on the same domain, just in different folders ( same parent folder)

directory structure:

parent site: [localhost/testSite]
web app 1 site: [localhost/testSite/webapp1]
web app 2 site: [localhost/testSite/webapp2]

web app 1 site sets a Session variable ("myVarImSetting")
web app 2 site gets a Session variable ("myVarImSetting")

after the project is compiled, run web app 1 first, to set the variable, then while its still open, browse to web app 2 page, and display the value stored in Session(myVarImSetting")

this should work, there should be a way of doing this, im told there is, but no one has offered any proof, and a working demo for .net 2.0 framework, using asp.net state server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/ASPNET/sharing-asp-net-session-state-between-we) is an article with code sample.

Comment: i guess this is the only solution for what i wanted to do, i will have to look for another way to combine the projects instead.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [Application variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178594.aspx) for this?

```
Application("myVarImSetting") = 5;
int mySetting = (int)Application("myVarImSetting");
```

Comment: uh i dont know? ive never used application variables before.. could this allow the passing of data between both applications? and can we just then null them out when the session dies?

Comment: i think this would be bad from the bit of reading i have done.. this will allow the value to be accessed by all users, i want to pass user specific data back and forth between two different web applications, thats why i want the session instead... unless you think we can use it the way we want to?.